# Terraform pass provider arguments from module to submodule

Tags: terraform, ibm-cloud

**Root module:**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    ibm = {
      source = "IBM-Cloud/ibm"
      version = ">= 1.50.0"
    }
  }
}
```

```
module "ibm-cloud-infr" {
  providers = {
    ibm = ibm.ibmcloud
  }
  source = "./modules/ibm-cloud"
}
```

```
provider "ibm" {
  alias                 = "ibmcloud"
  region                = var.region
  zone                  = var.zone
  ibmcloud_api_key      = var.ibmcloud_api_key
  iaas_classic_username = var.iaas_classic_username
  iaas_classic_api_key  = var.iaas_classic_api_key
}
```

**Module `ibm-cloud-infr`:**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    ibm = {
      source = "IBM-Cloud/ibm"
      version = ">= 1.50.0"
    }
  }
}
```

```
resource "ibm_resource_group" "VMware" {
  name = "VMware"
}
```

```
module "vsphere-site" {
  providers = {
    # The question is here
  }
  source = "./modules/vsphere-site"
}
```

**Sub module `vsphere-site`:**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    ibm = {
      source = "IBM-Cloud/ibm"
      version = ">= 1.50.0"
    }
  }
}
```

```
# Some resources using the provider
```

**Question:**
The provider required by the sub module `vsphere-site` needs to be supplied with an argument from the resource (`ibm_resource_group.VMware`) from the module `ibm-cloud-infr`. The argument would be something like following,

```
provider "ibm" {
  # ...
  resource_group = ibm_resource_group.VMware.id
}
```

According to the terraform documentation, the providers can only be defined in the root module (0th level) which makes sense but in this case, one of the arguments to the provider that needs to be passed to the sub module (2nd level) is only known in the 1st level module. Is there a way to override or pass additional arguments to the providers (passed from the root module) at the module level (>=1) ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define variables in the module block. They would then be used to pass down the settings you need. The example is taken from an IBM Cloud solution tutorial which has [a module to deploy context-based restrictions](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/secure-file-storage/blob/master/terraform/cbr.tf):

```
# CBR objects are integrated as optional module
module "cbr_objects" {
  count                = var.deploy_cbr ? 1 : 0
  source               = "./cbr"
  iks_cluster_name     = var.iks_cluster_name
  cbr_enforcement_mode = var.cbr_enforcement_mode
  cos                  = ibm_resource_instance.cos
  keyprotect           = ibm_resource_instance.keyprotect
  cbr_homezone_iprange = var.cbr_homezone_iprange
}
```

Similarly, you would define what you need:

`resource_group_vmware_id = ibm_resource_group.VMware.id`